# jquery multiple click events over animated div

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

What I wanna achieve is animate a div up and down until next click when it should stop and wait for another click to start animating again.

http://jsfiddle.net/WwJRD/

this is the function animating my div:

```
function upAndDown(element,x) {

    $(element).animate({'top':'+='+x+'px'}, 'slow')
    .animate({'top':'-='+x+'px'}, 'slow',function(){upAndDown(element,x)});
};

$('.clickThis').click(function(){
    upAndDown('.moveThis',50);
});
```

I really dont know how to get what I want!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a little tricky, because you have multiple queued animations and a callback.

The problem is if you just `stop`, and then call `upAndDown` later, you will start animating from the current position, meaning you might move around the page sporadically.  You can't `jumpToEnd` in the `stop()` call either, because you will still call the callback.

I fixed this by adding a class `moving` when (appropriately) the object is moving.  This is used in the callback to decide whether to keep animating.

You end up with this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EkpNK/

Now, this keeps animating until it finishes a cycle.  If you want to have it stop immediately, you can call `.stop(false, true)` twice to stop both animations and return to the original spot:

http://jsfiddle.net/EkpNK/1/

If you want to stop in place and continue from where you left off, it will take some extra code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar to Jeff B's, but keeps things (IMO) a little cleaner, and uses jQuery.data() function to store the "animating" flag instead of adding/removing classes:

http://jsfiddle.net/HnK98/